# How to repack the monobundleapp

Tags: android, c#

I recently had to make a version of a survivalcraft 2 mod that allowed circuits to run faster

I found this script by stack overflow to unpack a mono bundle app

I already modified the .dll, but I need to repack it, and I don't know anything about pyelftools

Script:

```
from elftools.elf.elffile import ELFFile
from zipfile import ZipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import gzip, string

data = open('libmonodroid_bundle_app.so').read()
f = StringIO(data)
elffile = ELFFile(f)
section = elffile.get_section_by_name('.dynsym')
for symbol in section.iter_symbols():
  if symbol['st_shndx'] != 'SHN_UNDEF' and symbol.name.startswith('assembly_data_'):
    print symbol.name
    dll_data = data[symbol['st_value']:symbol['st_value']+symbol['st_size']]
    dll_data = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(dll_data)).read()
    outfile = open(symbol.name[14:].replace('_dll', '.dll'), 'w+'); print symbol.name[14:].replace('_dll', '.dll')
    outfile.write(dll_data)
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: any way to repack libmonodroid_bundle_app.so ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I already created a script, However, It probably won't work, Although, There is a folder called assemblies without the mono bundle, you will probably just need to zip the extracted dlls, create the folder, and delete the mono bundle

However, I'm not sure, but anything is possible :)